# drag lines in html map and display difference between lines

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been checking different questions about this topic but none of them gives me a convincing answer. I have a map in which I've plotted 4 axis by doing the following:

```
function axis() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var NECorner = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var SWCorner = bounds.getSouthWest();

    // horizontal top axis

    var PolylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat()-0.0002, NECorner.lng()),
        new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat()-0.0002, SWCorner.lng()),
    ];

    var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        clickable: false,
        geodesic: true,
        path: PolylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.000000,
        strokeWeight: 0.8
    });

    Path.setMap(map);

    // horizontal low axis

    var PolylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat()+0.0002, NECorner.lng()),
        new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat()+0.0002, SWCorner.lng()),
    ];

    var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        clickable: false,
        geodesic: true,
        path: PolylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.000000,
        strokeWeight: 0.8
    });

    Path.setMap(map);

    // vertical left axis

    var PolylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat(), SWCorner.lng()+0.0002),
        new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat(), SWCorner.lng()+0.0002),
    ];

    var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        clickable: false,
        geodesic: true,
        path: PolylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.000000,
        strokeWeight: 0.8
    });

    Path.setMap(map);

    // vertical left axis

    var PolylineCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(NECorner.lat(), NECorner.lng()-0.0002),
        new google.maps.LatLng(SWCorner.lat(), NECorner.lng()-0.0002),
    ];

    var Path = new google.maps.Polyline({
        clickable: false,
        geodesic: true,
        path: PolylineCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1.000000,
        strokeWeight: 0.8
    });

    Path.setMap(map);
}
```

what I want now is to be able to drag these axis horizontally or vertically (depending on the axis) and constantly get the position difference between them (between the horizontals on the one hand and between the vertical ones on the other one).

My output is this one:
[image]
In case the question is not clear enough, I want to:

-be able to move/sweep the four red lines by dragging them with the mouse

-show the value of: abs(latitude_axis1 -latitude-axis2) and abs(longitude_axis1 -longitude-axis2) above the map

Can anyone help me? if not, does anyone know a similar question that has been answered (I think that I have checked them all)

Comment: What do you mean by "get the position difference"? And what exactly do you want to drag? The complete line/path or only the point?

Comment: @Dekel I've edited the question a little bit, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code is not dummy proof, like it doesn't stop the user from taking the north line under the south line, and it's not impossible to drag the lines too far, ...

But this is (more or less) what you requested.

Replace your API key

EDIT: notice, on line 46, you can change 'dragend' to 'drag'.  Then the display is changed while the user is dragging

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>drag lines in html map and display difference between lines</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #map {
            height: 90%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39370766/drag-lines-in-html-map-and-display-difference-between-lines/39376480#39376480">Stackoverflow</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var initialViewportCoordinates = {
          north: 51.0,
          east:  5.0,
          south: 50.0,
          west: 3.0
        };
        var extraDegrees = 10;  // the lines will extend 10 degrees (which is pretty much) 
        var lineObjects = [];

        function drawPolyline(path, color) {
            var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: path,
                draggable: true,
                strokeColor: color,
                strokeOpacity: 0.9,
                strokeWeight: 3
            });
            line.setMap(map);
            // drag event
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(line, 'dragend', function(e) {
              // find out which line is being dragged
              var index = lineObjects.indexOf(this);
              // update initialViewportCoordinates
              switch(index) {
                case 0: initialViewportCoordinates.north = e.latLng.lat(); break;
                case 1: initialViewportCoordinates.east =  e.latLng.lng(); break;
                case 2: initialViewportCoordinates.south = e.latLng.lat(); break;
                case 3: initialViewportCoordinates.west =  e.latLng.lng(); break;
              }
              displayDifference();
            });
            return line;
        }
        function displayDifference() {
          document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 
            'difference lat: ' + (initialViewportCoordinates.north - initialViewportCoordinates.south) + '<br/>' +
            'difference lng: ' + (initialViewportCoordinates.east - initialViewportCoordinates.west) 
            ;
        }
        function drawViewport() {
          var north = [
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.north , lng: initialViewportCoordinates.east + extraDegrees},
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.north, lng: initialViewportCoordinates.west - extraDegrees}
          ];
          var east = [
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.north + extraDegrees , lng: initialViewportCoordinates.east},
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.south - extraDegrees, lng: initialViewportCoordinates.east}
          ];
          var south = [
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.south , lng: initialViewportCoordinates.east + extraDegrees},
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.south, lng: initialViewportCoordinates.west - extraDegrees}
          ];
          var west = [
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.north + extraDegrees , lng: initialViewportCoordinates.west},
            {lat: initialViewportCoordinates.south - extraDegrees, lng: initialViewportCoordinates.west}
          ];
          // we will genetate the lines and store the resulting objects in this array
          lineObjects = [
            drawPolyline(north, '#ff0000'),
            drawPolyline(east, '#ff0000'),
            drawPolyline(south, '#ff0000'),
            drawPolyline(west, '#ff0000')
          ];
        }
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: 50.84, lng: 4.35},
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            });
            drawViewport();
            displayDifference();
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this works perfectly. I just have to make the axis resize when any zoom is detected and I'll finish. your were really helpful!